# Can I Delete entire table without undo in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

I have a table that was working great until recently. I have a program that interacts with this table the steps are...

1. Delete all records
2. Load all records

Recently the number of records seems to have started to overload our SQL instance and when I try to run the delete command I get....

```
ORA-30036: unable to extend segment by 128 in undo tablespace 'name'
```

I tried using truncate but I don't have permissions. Is there a way I can delete without the undo tablespace? This is with SQL developer but I would also like it to work with the JDBC connection.

Comment: What does it mean, "you don't have permission" (to truncate it)? Do you own the table? Because, truncate would reset the high water mark.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by removing every row then inserting them? Are you just refreshing the data from somewhere else - then use a merge statement so that only the required modifications are made and undo/redo is only generated for that. Truncate is a logical corruption waiting to happen if your table is being queried - your users do not want Schrödinger‘s table which is sometimes populated and sometimes not.

Comment: This is a valid remark @AndrewSayer, but you should also mention that a `merge` is *less performant*, *more complex*, *more error prone* and *requires primary key*. So if a *mantainace window* is possible the `truncate` - `insert` option is clearly prefered.

Comment: @AndrewSayer It depends on the tasks. This may be some stage of ETL process so there's no need to merge something. There's a choice between load speed and availability, sometimes users may just try again in a 30 seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you are trying to *simulate* the functionality of the `TRANCATE TABLE` in your `DELETE`statement.

So you should definitively *use* `TRUNCATE TABLE` as it produces much less `UNDO` and also it deallocates the space used up to the `MINEXTENTS`.

If the table is not in the accessing user schema, you would need the privilege `DROP ANY TABLE`  which may be problem to receive.

A simple workaround is to define a stored procedure in the schema of the table that executes (immediate) the `TRUNCATE` and only ask for the `EXECUTE` grant for this procedure.

Comment: Wrapping in the stored proc worked for me